# Shared pointers do not intrinsically cast to base/derived types

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, casting, shared-ptr

**What I did:** I recently started to write a multi-threaded producer-consumer-style queue. Initially, I went with smart pointers but ended up changing all of them to raw pointers and managing their lifetime and their memory management manually (code at the end, if interested).

**What I'm looking for:** arguments for or against this conjecture:

> Inheritance can't sit in the same room as shared pointers, as nicely as it would with raw pointers and reference objects.

**My Reasoning:**
`Base` and `Derived` objects are covariant. So are raw pointers (`Base*` and `Derived*`). Shared pointers (`shared_ptr<Base>` and `shared_ptr<Derived>`) are not.

The programmer has to do many conceptually unnecessary downcasting using `dynamic_pointer_cast`, which makes the code ugly and are somewhat expensive at compile time and run time.

This makes me wonder if shared pointers should be avoided in object-oriented designs, as their benefits do not overweigh their expense and headache.

---

**My code before change** (multi-threading is left out for the sake of readability):

```
typedef shared_ptr<Animal> animal_ptr;
typedef shared_ptr<Dog> dog_ptr;

class Buffer {
private:
    mutex mu_;
    condition_variable cond_;
    deque<shared_ptr<Animal> > buffer_;
public:
    void add(shared_ptr<Animal> req) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu_);
        cond_.wait(locker, [this](){return buffer_.size() < size_;});
        buffer_.push_back(req);
        locker.unlock();
        cond_.notify_all();
    }

    shared_ptr<Animal> remove() {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu_);
        cond_.wait(locker, [this](){return buffer_.size() > 0;});
        shared_ptr<Animal> back = buffer_.back();
        buffer_.pop_back();
        locker.unlock();
        cond_.notify_all();
    }
};

int main() {
    Buffer buffer;
    animal_ptr bPtr1 (new Animal()); // buffer.add() works just fine
    dog_ptr    dPtr1 (new Dog());    // EDIT: works fine too.
    animal_ptr dptr2 (new Dog());    // EDIT: it's okay
    ...
    buffer.remove();                 // returns a base class object, requires downcasting to access derived members
```

### }

**EDIT** for more clarification, and why shared pointers are treating inheritence differently than raw pointers:

```
void func1(shared_ptr<Animal> ptr);
void func2(Animal* ptr);
...
Dog* rawPtr = new Dog();
func1(dPtr1); // is not possible, requires upcasting
func2(rawPtr); // is ok.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `returns error`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/518ccd53897ea6b3

Comment: My second question is what do you mean by `requires upcasting before buffer.add()`? See my previous code example.

Comment: @AndyG Your second comment is valid too. My mistake was that I forgot to inherit from `class Animal` in my simple code, hence all the misconceptions.

Comment: I still don't understand the need to upcast and downcast...

Comment: @VermillionAzure I explained: calling buffer.remove() gives you a shared_ptr<Animal>, which is not automatically castable to shahred_ptr<Dog>, and requires runtime check with dynamic_pointer_cast

Comment: @narengi Well, of course! You can't assume that a base class can immediately be cast to a derived class because that assumption isn't valid. If you were to do something like use a variant, perhaps that might be more valid, or maybe you could use virtual functions or something.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain the reason?

Comment: @narengi First of all, this isn't really a question or issue--you don't outline a specific issue that confirms your "problem." I don't see any real evidence that smart pointers are bad with inheritance--your problem is with that you need to downcast the pointer, which is a pointer and type problem, not a smart pointer problem.

Comment: Why does using raw pointers rather than smart pointers magically negate the need for casting? If you mean it removes the need for `dynamic_cast`, then you are not safely casting your pointers in the raw pointer version.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't magically eliminate the need for dynamic casting, as they base pointer and derived pointer are covariant.

Comment: @narengi I know that it doesn't. What is your argument for using raw pointers instead, then?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode that you need (explicit) casting for converting derived shared pointer to base, but you don't need that for raw pointers.

Comment: Yes you do. There is no difference. You put a comment in your example saying "is not possible, requires upcasting", but that is simply not true. Please add your compiler error to your example as well. You also seem to be using upcasting and downcasting interchangeably, when in fact they are quite different.

Comment: Please define "covariant"

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand the problems that you are having. If you consistently use shared_ptr everywhere, you are able to pass shared_ptr objects of Base and Derived the same as raw pointers. I fleshed out the example that you gave.

The problem comes when you mix shared_ptr and raw pointers. The first problem goes away with overloading, where the shared_ptr function forwards to the function taking a raw pointer where the real work is done. The second problem goes away when calling with the underlying raw pointer obtained from the shared pointer.

```
class Animal
{
public:
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
};

using std::shared_ptr;

typedef shared_ptr<Animal> animal_ptr;
typedef shared_ptr<Dog> dog_ptr;

class Buffer {
private:
    std::deque<shared_ptr<Animal> > buffer_;
public:
    void add(shared_ptr<Animal> req) {
        buffer_.push_back(req);
    }

    shared_ptr<Animal> remove() {
        shared_ptr<Animal> back = buffer_.back();
        buffer_.pop_back();
    }
};

void func1(Animal* ptr)
{}

void func1(shared_ptr<Animal> ptr)
{
    func1(ptr.get());
}

void func2(Animal* ptr)
{}


int main() 
{
    Buffer buffer;
    animal_ptr bPtr1(new Animal()); // buffer.add() works just fine
    dog_ptr    dPtr1(new Dog());    // requires upcasting before buffer.add()
    animal_ptr dptr2(new Dog());    // returns error, as they are covariant

    Dog* rawPtr = new Dog();
    func2(rawPtr); // is ok.
    func1(dPtr1); // is ok.

    func1(rawPtr); // requires overloading func1 with shared_ptr and raw pointer signatures
    func2(dPtr1.get()); // is okay when using underlying raw ptr

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No error in the code. As I explained, it results in **unnecessary downcasting**. For example, let's say you have Dog::print(), which is specific to Dog, and Animal doesn't have it. You have to dynamic cast the resulted shared pointer that you get from the Buffer to be able to access that method.

Comment: @narengi This is the case with regular pointers as well... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43cb83137794da6

Comment: Yes, as VermillionAzure says, that is the case with regular pointers too. I have had no problems using shared_ptr instances to replace raw pointers. Can you provide an example where shared_ptr behaves differently?

Comment: @VermillionAzure please see the edit, if it makes sense.

Comment: @narengi Good. You should've opened with that example in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with mixing shared_ptr and raw pointers! When I consistently use shared_ptr everywhere, I have no (or at least few) problems. I will update my answer with a few comments and changes.

Answer (score 0):

#### No, it works.

```
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2a83c740ed60521

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
  void print() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
  void print() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

void print(std::shared_ptr<A> a) {
    a->print();
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr_a(new A);
  std::shared_ptr<B> ptr_b(new B);
  
  ptr_a->print();
  ptr_b->print();
  
  ptr_b->A::print();
  
  //THIS WORKS!
  print(ptr_a);
  print(ptr_b);
}
```

The last two "A" print correctly. The reason your function doesn't work is because `Dog* != std::shared_ptr<Dog>`.

Comment: you're missing a `virtual` in `A::print`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Yeah, you're right. I suppose this could be optional depending on how he wants the behavior to go.

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr<derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<base>`, so you should have no errors in passing a derived pointer to a function that takes a base pointer unless you are using a bad compiler.

An example function that compiles fine:

```
class animal{
    public:
        virtual auto print() const -> void = 0;
};

class dog: public animal{
    public:
        auto print() const -> void{ std::cout << "I'm a Dog!\n"; }
};

class cat: public animal{
    public:
        auto print() const -> void{ std::cout << "I'm not a Dog!\n"; }
};

auto func(std::shared_ptr<animal> ptr){
    ptr->print();
}

auto main() -> int{
    auto dog_ptr = std::make_shared<dog>();
    auto cat_ptr = std::make_shared<cat>();
    func(dog_ptr);
    func(cat_ptr);
}
```

Will print:

```
I'm a Dog!
I'm not a Dog!
```